Without Cause, For Nothing, or In the End (Isaiah 52:4)

The Hebrew be'epes comes from the root word ephes meaning 'a ceasing'. What would cause the translation to become without cause or for nothing and not in the end or at the end, to parallel at first earlier in the verse?
For thus says the Lord God, into Egypt went down My people at first to dwell there, and Assyria in the end oppressed them.

I'm an amateur at Ancient Hebrew but this seems to be a straightforward case of a root word having a preposition added:-

בְּ (be): This means "in" or "with."
https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Gesenius%27_Hebrew_Grammar/102._Prefixed_Prepositions
אֶ֥פֶס (efes): As the OP has it, this means "nothing" or "empty."

So they go into Egypt and the Assyrian people oppress them in+empty = for nothing.
I think בָרִֽאשֹׁנָ֖ה=at first is picked up in the next verse by וְעַתָּ֤ה=therefore now.
The lexicon entry for בְּאֶ֥פֶס doesn't have any temporal sense to mean 'in the end' or any consecutive sense like 'with the result that'. It's an adverb about the futility and emptiness of the Assyrians' action. This is Brown-Driver-Briggs usage 2b. There are similar usages in Strongs:-
Job 7:6 - without hope
Proverbs 14:28 - a lack of people
Proverbs 26:20 - a lack of wood
There is the idiom אַפְסֵי־ אָ֑רֶץ e.g. at Psalm 72:8 "the ends of the earth", but that's (1) a construct form and (2) it's an idiom and probably the direct precursor to the English idiom. End doesn't exactly mean end in our idiom and it's the same for אַפְסֵי־ in Hebrew. Brown-Driver-Briggs has this for their sense 1 but the part about "only in the poetic phrase" is important. Perhaps English should say "to the non-existence of the earth," till we run out of ground.

It is true that the primary meaning of the noun אֶפֶס ('ephes) in Isa 52:4 is "a ceasing", and thus, has two uses (BDB):

"end or extremity", eg, Deut 33;17, 1 Sam 2:10, Micah 5:3, jer 16:19, Ps 2:8, 59:14, 72:8, etc
by extension "non-existence".  Thus, the word can mean "nothing", eg, Isa 34:12, 40:17, 41:24, etc

The best translations appear to actually say this:

ESV: For thus says the Lord GOD: “My people went down at the first into Egypt to sojourn there, and the Assyrian oppressed them for nothing.

It is only a small semantic step to arrive at a translation that says: "without cause" or similar.  Note the comment of the Cambridge commentary:

without cause i.e. probably, “for nought,” without having acquired any right over Israel by services rendered to Jehovah. The meaning can
hardly be that Israel suffered innocently.

The Jamieson-Fausset-Brown Bible Commentary is similar:

without cause—answering to "for naught" in Isa 52:5; it was an act of
gratuitous oppression in the present case, as in that case.

